# Duplicate values being added to ArrayList

Tags: java, sqlite, arraylist

I have created a custom list adapter and I am trying to list the data from an SQLite database. My list is outputting the correct amount of DB records, but has duplicated the final DB item many times (same amount of times as there are items in the DB).

I have this code:

```
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONArray arr = null;
        db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        arr = db.getSynced();
        db.close();
        DiaryItems diary = new DiaryItems();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String ass_id = c.getString(TAG_ASSID);
                String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                String cname = c.getString(TAG_CNAME);
                String cno = c.getString(TAG_CNO);
                String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                String complete = c.getString(TAG_COMPLETE);
                System.out.println("ASS ID: " + ass_id); //works - prints ass_id 1->10
                diary.setAss_id(ass_id);
                diary.setTime(time);
                diary.setCname(cname);
                diary.setCno(cno);
                diary.setType(type);
                diary.setComplete(complete);
                diaryList.add(diary);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < diaryList.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("ASSIGN ID: " + diaryList.get(j).getAss_id());
                //this prints this correct size of items, but the array only contains 
                //the values of the last item parsed in the JSON
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray array) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            System.out.println("Dismissed dialog");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (diaryList != null) {
            DiaryListAdapter adapter = new DiaryListAdapter(getActivity(), diaryList);
            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have instantiated the diary object outside for loop so ultimately same instance is being set in each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same `DiaryItems` instance multiple times to the `List`. You should create a new `DiaryItems` instance in each iteration of your loop.

Change

```
    DiaryItems diary = new DiaryItems();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            ....
```

to

```
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            DiaryItems diary = new DiaryItems();
            ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You've Instantiated `DiaryItems diary = new DiaryItems();` 
outside of your for loop.  Create it inside the loops and you won't be adding it every time the loop ends.  Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    DiaryItems diary = new DiaryItems();
    ..do stuff
}
```

instead of:

```
DiaryItems diary = new DiaryItems();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);
```